# Overlapping grids and some of the features are not working

Tags: qt

[image: problem with overlapping grids]

I have a problem as follows:

In the figure I have different layers of a conductor. By selecting different conductors, the cable views change accordingly. But the cable views grid is overlapping with cable layers grid as the size of image grows for different layers. So when I reach to Sheath, Insulator etc., I'm unable to select the item in check box. I tried to reduce the pixel size of the image but it is not working and there are different properties for each layer that get popped up when i click it. That window in the image is the maximized window.

Can someone suggest a solution for this?